# Sorting columns and selecting top 'n' from a grouped column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to groupby on column 'pidx' and then find the top 3 'day_no' with the highest score.

The result I am looking is something like this:

[image]

What I tried was:

```
df.sort(['pidx','score'],ascending = False).groupby('pidx').head(2)
```

It works partially, but I don't get the expected result.

What other method can I use to get the result with the desired dataframe format?

Comment: You generally get help faster if you include a copy/pastable example dataframe definition in your question.

Comment: Why does it only work partially, what's different from your expectation? .head(2) should not give you 3 results, it only gives you 2, change it to 3 and it should be 3 as described in the problem. Also, it should be df.sort_values, not df.sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(['pidx','score'],ascending = False).groupby('pidx').head(3)
```

It's kind of similar to what you posted, but I fixed some syntax issues. If the result is different from what you expected, please explain the difference.

Comment: It works as intended. Now I can see what I was doing wrong. Thank you.